R data.table - update each row by aggregating other rows satisfying a condition
I have the following table.
dt = data.table(id = 1:5, intMask = c(11,14,8,1,13), imprint = c("1011", "1110", "1000", "0001", "1101"), N = c(3,3,1,1,3), mass = c(.05,.1,.15,.3,.4))
   id intMask imprint N mass
1:  1      11    1011 3 0.05
2:  2      14    1110 3 0.10
3:  3       8    1000 1 0.15
4:  4       1    0001 1 0.30
5:  5      13    1101 3 0.40

Assume that the imprint column represents a binary representation of a set (i.e. here we have subsets of a set of cardinality 5). intMask represents the respective integer corresponding to the binary representation. N respective cardinality - i.e. number of 1s in the representation.
I would like to update the sum by summating all rows corresponding to respective supersets. I propose using the bitwAnd() function with column intMask to find respective supersets efficiently.
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  i.intMask <- dt[i,intMask]
  i.N <- dt[i,N]
  dt[i, newMass := sum(dt[N >= i.N,][bitwAnd(intMask, i.intMask) == i.intMask, mass])]
}

I.e. to get
dt[]
   id intMask imprint N mass newMass
1:  1      11    1011 3 0.05    0.05
2:  2      14    1110 3 0.10    0.10
3:  3       8    1000 1 0.15    0.70
4:  4       1    0001 1 0.30    0.75
5:  5      13    1101 3 0.40    0.04

Assume thousands of rows. Do you have an idea of how to do it efficiently? Preferably using data.table updating?

using set() within the loop instead of DT[] will give a performance boost.

Efficiently in what sense? Memory, cpu time, ...?

Efficiency in the sense of a running time.

Another approach is the following, which should works much faster than brute-force for large dataset:

create all supersets
sum mass by superset
left join original data with 2.

get_all_superset <- function(x){
  
  get_superset <- function(x){
    n <- stringr::str_count(x,"1")
    super1 <- expand.grid(replicate(n, 0:1, simplify = FALSE))
    allbit <- stringr::str_split_1(x,"")
    for(i in seq(length(allbit))){
      if(allbit[i]=="0"){
        super1 <- tibble::add_column(super1,0,.before=i)
      }
    }
    return(do.call(paste0,c(super1)))
  }
  lapply(x,get_superset)
}

dt[dt[,list(super=unlist(get_all_superset(imprint))),by=mass][,.(new_mass=sum(mass)),by=super],on=c(imprint="super"),new_mass:=i.new_mass]
dt

   id intMask imprint N mass new_mass
1:  1      11    1011 3 0.05     0.05
2:  2      14    1110 3 0.10     0.10
3:  3       8    1000 1 0.15     0.70
4:  4       1    0001 1 0.30     0.75
5:  5      13    1101 3 0.40     0.40

Equivalently in dplyr:

df$super <- get_all_superset(df$imprint)
superdf <- tidyr::unnest(df, cols = super) %>%
  reframe(new_mass=sum(mass),.by=super)
merge(df%>%select(-super),superdf ,all.x=T,by.x="imprint",by.y="super")

  imprint id intMask N mass new_mass
1    0001  4       1 1 0.30     0.75
2    1000  3       8 1 0.15     0.70
3    1011  1      11 3 0.05     0.05
4    1101  5      13 3 0.40     0.40
5    1110  2      14 3 0.10     0.10


This might be one option
dt[
    dt[
        dt,
        c(
            id = .(i.id),
            newMass = .(mass * (bitwAnd(intMask, i.intMask) == i.intMask))
        ),
        on = .(N >= N)
    ][, lapply(.SD, sum), id],
    on = .(id)
]

which gives
      id intMask imprint     N  mass newMass
   <int>   <num>  <char> <num> <num>   <num>
1:     1      11    1011     3  0.05    0.05
2:     2      14    1110     3  0.10    0.10
3:     3       8    1000     1  0.15    0.70
4:     4       1    0001     1  0.30    0.75
5:     5      13    1101     3  0.40    0.40

